# Button in same cell on each sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to put a button in the top left corner (A1) of each sheet that returns to the home sheet. I can't get it to add on all the sheets - it stops after the first sheet.

The below is what I've come up with.

```
Sub addhome()
    Dim btn As Button
    Dim t As Range


    For Each sh In Worksheets

        Set t = sh.Range("A1")
        Set btn = sh.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        With btn
          .OnAction = "GotoHome"
          .Caption = "Home"
          .Name = "Home"
        End With    

    Next sh

    MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

It works when I open a new workbook and make a few dummy sheets, but when I try to do it on my existing workbook, it only adds a button on the first sheet.

Comment: Add `Dim sh as Worksheet` before the `For` loop.  Does that help?

Comment: your code works for me. Adds button on all sheets. May be you have some more code on events and with a Resume Next.

Comment: @BruceWayne I think you mean `Dim sh as Worksheet`?

Comment: @dwirony - D'oh, yes!

Comment: Also, where is this code? It should be in a Workbook Module.  Add `Debug.Print sh.Name` before `Set t = ...` and see if the proper worksheet names are being returned in the Immediate Window (press CTRL+G with the VBEditor open to access it).  Finally, add `Option Explicit` to the *very top* of the code, above `Sub ...` to check for any typos in variable names, etc.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, Perrin - your code works fine for me.

Comment: Does naming the worksheets affect this? I'm wondering if that is my problem. I also have a whole list of buttons on the first sheet for other purposes that may be getting in the way..

Comment: No, worksheet names should not matter.

Comment: @PerrinRomney In your existing workbook, are you positive column A isn't hidden on all the worksheets? Is cell `A1` a merged cell?

Comment: @BruceWayne this is in a module on my personal macro workbook. Your debug only prints my first worksheet on this particular file, although it prints all sheet names for other files.

Comment: @dwirony A1 is not merged or hidden - there are no merged or hidden cells in my entire workbook.

Comment: Are getting any errors?

Comment: @0m3r - No errors showing.

Comment: Also just realized - the button created doesn't have the name "Home" when it has this error.

Comment: Where is the code? in `personal.xlsb` or in `Workbook`?

Comment: Why not create your first sheet with the button, then use the "move copy" sheet function to duplicate the sheet as many times as required?

Comment: In Personal. I think the issue is the "With btn" finding the button on a page full of buttons.

Comment: Add a `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name` and `Debug.Print Worksheets.Count` and see what those return...

Comment: If your code is in `personal.xlsb` then use `For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` - You need to let the code know which `WorkBook` your working with

Comment: I made a macro that deleted my original buttons on the first page, and after I created and deleted one button manually on the page, the original code worked. Not sure what gremlins were lurking. @brucewayne your comment on the debug line helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever considered creating a custom ribbon for this?  Using a custom ribbon, you only need the one "Home" button.  Google "Custom UI Builder for MIcrosoft Office" and you'll find a bunch of information on custom ribbon creation.  It's not that hard to do and once you get the hang of it, you'll never put another button on a sheet ever again.

Comment: @frank I will check that out for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this situation - hopefully it will help someone in the future..

```
Sub addhome()

Dim btn As Button
Dim t As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Worksheets

    Debug.Print sh.Name
If sh.Name = "All" Then

Else

    Set t = sh.Range("A1")
    Set btn = sh.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)


    With btn
      .OnAction = "GotoHome"
      .Caption = "Home"
      .Name = "Home"
    End With
End If

Next sh



MsgBox ("done")

End Sub
```

I just used an IF-THEN to avoid the problem sheet and hit all the others. Wish I would have thought of that yesterday. I know there were easier ways to do it with copying, but I enjoy the challenge of finding the most universally accurate way. I think this is close to it. Thanks for all your help.